Movie about a cartoonist whose creation became alive and attack him
I'm looking for a movie that I saw when I was a kid in the 80's.
I remember only small parts of the movie. It ends with a cartoonist being attacked by his drawings, represented by a army of little white and black characters.

The movie was dubbed in Portuguese, so I do not know. However, at that time, 95% of the movies were American, so we can (almost) safely assume it was in English.
It was not a short movie, probably had a little more than one hour of running time
Yes, it had dialogues. If I am not mistaken, the guy was in some sort of crisis with his ex-wife. 
Can't remember the face of the actors. I already tried to research this in the internet several times, but to no avail. If I could remember the name of one of the characters or the actors, I would have something more substantial to base my searches.
The cartoons attack the cartoonist in the end of the movie and there is a scene where he grabs some of them and throws them in a blender.

Sorry, I wish I could be more specific, but it has more than 25 years since I saw this movie.

What was the country\language? Was it a short film or feature length? Was there any dialogue? What did the cartoonist look like?

@Walt, I edited the question with your questions. Sorry for not being able to clarify more.

Thanks, that's very helpful. I have a hunch this could be The War Between Men and Women from 1972 with Jack Lemmon, though I don't remember it at all, let alone the blender part. See if the trailer rings any bells.

Are you sure it's the 80s, and not early 90s? This sounds like the 1992 Cool World

@Walt, fantastic!!! You have no idea how many years I was trying to find this movie :-) I saw this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAbj85Fa9Pc) and it was the movie!!!! Could you please reply to the question so I can accept the answer?

@cde, no, it's not, thank you for your attention.

No problem, I'll put it up. Glad you found it. :)

It's The War Between Men and Women from 1972 with Jack Lemmon and Barbara Harris.

2 quirky Manhattanites crash into each other cute at an ophthalmologist's office. Peter is a grouchy cartoonist/author whose vision is failing, divorced mother Theresa is also reluctant to plunge into a relationship right now. It's not love at first sight - both have their eyes dilated, plus Peter constantly lampoons women in his work, which book seller Theresa knows well. Loosely based on James Thurber's drawings "The War Between Men & Women," and Thurber's life, the film features animated sequences. .

Peter's black & white cartoons attack him, which you can briefly see in a foreign trailer around 0:26:



